Configure clangd for C11
I'm using macOS, Emacs, eglot, clangd for writing C11 code. However, the LSP functionality gives me help as if I were programming C++: e.g. suggests completion from std:: namespace (see the screenshot).
How can I configure clangd to use C11 specifically? Am I using it wrong? Should I be using another language server?

What is the extension of the file you are typing this into? If it's .c, clangd should know to parse it as a C file.

I'm using .c  and .h file extensions.

So, in .c files, you should not get C++ completion proposals. If you're getting them, please share clangd logs for further diagnosis. For .h files, clangd relies on the presence of a compile_commands.json file (see https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup) to find a source file whose command to use for parsing the .h file. The idea would be that in a C project, the entries in the compile_commands.json file are .c files, and clangd therefore parses the .h file in C mode.
